# Render all possible elements or render on request

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

So I have an app that has a right sidebar whose visibility is toggled via a button. In that sidebar there can be one of several things [at a time] - chat, help, search. I was looking at some plain HTML from apps which have a similar feature and noticed that they have all nodes rendered, but are just hidden via CSS.

Since I need to do the same thing, I was thinking whether this would be a good idea to do with React. But then I realized that React elements have a state which when updated calls the render method. So I can use the state to store both whether the sidebar is opened, and what is inside the sidebar.

Is that the React way of doing things? Is it better to have all nodes rendered even if they are not visible, or is it better to have the nodes rendered on request via state changes?

Answer (score 0):

My feeling is that only rendering what is visible would be the more standard React way, but in this case, this is mainly a performance decision. If you render everything and just toggle visibility with CSS, the first render will take longer (but the time difference may not be relevant or even noticeable). If you render only the part that's visible, React needs to do a small rerender every time the sidebar content changes. (This may also not be noticeable time.)

My recommendation would be to try both, if you want to test the performance. But I think you won't go too wrong either way.

Comment: I feel that the rerender is the more React way of doing it. But yes, it seems that this is dependent on how much people will be switching between tabs and what default connection speed/sent data is.

Comment: I would advise against fetching the information in the sidebar on every tab switch, because that duration would certainly be noticeable. But you can still have the data in the element state, without rendering it.